# Update logGroup retention for existing logs in CloudWatch using CloudFormationTemplate

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to update the logs retention of existing log groups created by my Lambda functions in CloudWatch using the CloudFormationTemplate in YAML.

In order to do that, I set

```
  LambdaCWRetentionPermissionsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*"

  LambdaCWRetentionPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/lambda/*"
      RetentionInDays: 14
```

But it does not seem to work, because it seems to try to create new log groups and they already exist. Is there a way that I can update the retention of already existing logs from CloudFormationTemplate in YAML?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Including logs:CreateLogGroup didn't update existing log group?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation has the function of importing existing resources. After importing, you can update the retention with the CloudFormation stack.

[Bringing existing resources into CloudFormation management - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

> If you created an AWS resource outside of AWS CloudFormation management, you can bring this existing resource into AWS CloudFormation management using resource import.